# Create A linq query with multiple where statements and left join

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a `LINQ` query that will render that following `SQL`. I am close but it still isn't correct.

**Desired SQL**

```
SELECT  

      TableDisplayColumns.Id
    , TableDisplayColumns.ViewName
    , TableDisplayColumns.ColumnName
    , TableDisplayColumns.ControllerName
    , TableDisplayColumns.TableDisplayName
    , TableDisplayColumns.IsVisibleByDefault

FROM dbo.TableDisplayColumns
LEFT JOIN dbo.UserTableDisplayColumns ON UserTableDisplayColumns.TableDisplayColumnId = TableDisplayColumns.Id

WHERE 
             (
                (TableDisplayColumns.IsVisibleByDefault = 1  AND UserTableDisplayColumns.IsNotVisible IS NULL)
                OR UserTableDisplayColumns.IsNotVisible = 0
             )
    AND (TableDisplayColumns.ControllerName = 'Contacts' AND TableDisplayColumns.ViewName = 'Index')
```

**Current SQL**

```
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'Index'
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = 'Contacts'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[ColumnName], [t0].[IsVisibleByDefault], [t0].[TableDisplayName], [t0].[ViewName]
FROM [TableDisplayColumns] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN ([UserTableDisplayColumns] AS [t1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [TableDisplayColumns] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[TableDisplayColumnId]) ON [t0].[Id] = [t1].[TableDisplayColumnId]
WHERE ([t0].[ViewName] = @p0) AND ([t0].[ControllerName] = @p1) AND ([t0].[IsVisibleByDefault] = 1) AND ([t2].[IsVisibleByDefault] = 1)
```

**Entities**

```
public class UserTableDisplayColumn
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TableDisplayColumnId { get; set; }

    public bool IsNotVisible { get; set; }

    public virtual TableDisplayColumn TableDisplayColumn { get; set; }
}

public class TableDisplayColumn
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50), Required]
    public string ViewName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50), Required]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50), Required]
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50), Required]
    public string TableDisplayName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsVisibleByDefault { get; set; }
}
```

Finally the current query:

```
    var query =  
            (
                from column in Context.TableDisplayColumns
                    .Where(x=>x.IsVisibleByDefault)
                    .Where(x=>x.ControllerName == "Contacts")
                    .Where(x=>x.ViewName == "Index")
                join userColumn in Context.UserTableDisplayColumns on column.Id equals userColumn.TableDisplayColumnId into userColumnColumns

                from userColumnColumn in userColumnColumns.DefaultIfEmpty()

                select new TableDisplayColumn()
                {
                    Id = column.Id,
                    ColumnName = column.ColumnName,
                    ControllerName = column.ColumnName,
                    IsVisibleByDefault = column.IsVisibleByDefault,
                    TableDisplayName = column.TableDisplayName,
                    ViewName = column.ViewName
                }
             ).ToList();
```

What I am trying to accomplish get the default column if there isn't anything in the `UsersColumns` Table. If there is a record in the `UsersColumns` then I want to only return if `IsNotVisible` = false.

Comment: LINQ isn't a SQL replacement. You are using an *ORM*, which means you don't have tables, you have *entities* with relations and properties. Use proper relations and navigation properties instead of trying to hard-code joins. It's the ORM's job to generate the joins based on the relations between *entities*

Comment: can you please give me an example of what you're saying?

Comment: Which ORM are you using? Entity Framework? LINQ by itself doesn't retrieve data from databases. As for examples, every ORM tutorials shows how to map tables to entities, create and confifure relations

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) shows how to configure a one-to-many relation in EF 6

Comment: thank you! I will read this.

Comment: creating the navigation property did the trick, thank you!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually, I disagree. LINQ is exactly a SQL replacement. Entity Framework is an ORM. Using LINQ to SQL you can just substitute for SQL.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) would help you translate? BTW, you appear to have an error in the `ControllerName` assignment in the `select`.

Comment: Also, if you are using EF, which version / type are you using? You appear to have a navigation property going in the opposite direction of your join for your query - is there some reason you don't have a reverse property?

Comment: @NetMage I am using EF6. I didnt know that i have a good reason for that. an answer with the correct query would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `let` keyword to bring in collections in a left join-ish way.

```
var query =
  from x in Context.TableDisplayColumns
  where x.ControllerName == "Contacts"
  where x.ViewName == "Index"
  let ys = Context.UserTableDisplayColumns.Where(y => y.TableDisplayColumnId == x.Id)
  where (x.IsVisibleByDefault && !ys.Any()) || ys.Any(y => y.IsNotVisible == 0)
  select x;
```